# What are matrix coefficients in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

What are matrix coefficients in linear algebra? And what does it mean "integer matrix coefficients"?

Comment: If you read this term from some sentence in some literature, quoting the sentence in your question would be helpful for the readers to understand the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix coefficients are the entries of the matrix. Integer matrix coefficients is just a matrix with integer entries.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the definition.

Comment: @J-unior Glad to help. Remember you always can upvote posts which are useful to you. You can [accept the answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/8271) is you consider it really answers your question.

Comment: I know, I'm not new at stackexchange. Still don't have enough rep to do this, and 10 minutes are not over yet :-)

Answer (score 6):

Note: there is a big difference between the terms "matrix coefficient" and "coefficient matrix". I'll explain first what you are probably asking about:

***Coefficient matrix***

Suppose you have a system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
1\cdot x_1 + 2x_2 &= 16\\
3x_1 + 1\cdot x_2 &= 4 \\
\end{align*}
\tag{1}$$

$(I)$ Then the ***[coefficient matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_matrix)*** (in this case, with integer entries) corresponding to this system of linear equations in $(1)$ is:

$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the entries in first column represents the coefficients of the $x_1$, and those in the second column the coefficients of $x_2$, etc..

The *augmented coefficient matrix* $M_a$ would include the entries in a third column which correspond to the values at the right of the equals signs in $(1)$:

$$M_a = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 &\;|\; 16\\
3 & 1 &|\; 4\;\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

***Matrix coefficient***

$(2)$ On the other hand, this coefficient matrix contrasts with what is meant by a [***matrix coefficient***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_coefficient). (Please read more at the given linked entry from Wikipedia: what follows is a brief excerpt from that entry.)

> In mathematics, a matrix coefficient (or matrix element) is a function on a group of a special form, which depends on a linear representation of the group and additional data. For the case of a finite group, matrix coefficients express the action of the elements of the group in the specified representation via the entries of the corresponding matrices.